# If $O\cap E \neq \emptyset$ for every non-empty open subset $O$ of $X$, then $\overline{E}=X$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I proved the converse myself. I'm trying to prove the other direction.
Here is my attempt.
Assume $\overline{E}\neq X$ for $E\subset X$. Then there exists some $x\in X \setminus \overline{E}$. It is obvious that this $x$ is an interior point of $X\setminus \overline{E}$ since $\overline{E}$ is closed. So, for some $r>0$, we have $N_r(x)\subset X\setminus \overline{E}$. This subset is clearly non-empty, and $N_r(x)\cap E=\emptyset$.

Is this proof ok? I have found several posts on this problem, but my proof was not exactly the same as any of them, which makes me worried if mine is alright.

Comment: It is OK if you are in a metric space. In a general topological space you won't get a number $r$. If you take $O=X\setminus \overline E$ you get a proof that alwasy works.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to write this $X$ is a metric space. Thank you!

Comment: Note that the complement of a closed set is an open set. So $O = X\setminus \overline E$ is an open set that does not intersect $E$. By the hypothesis, it can only be the empty set.